# Is there any way I can call this getter and consistently get the expected result?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, race-condition

I need to use a property getter from a 3rd-party API, and just accessing that getter *sometimes* hangs the entire application, *sometimes* works (in dev/debugger). And if I deploy it to a production server, the host application *sometimes* works as expected, *sometimes* dies with an APPCRASH in KERNEL32.

I couldn't understand how a simple getter could freeze up or crash anything, so I though maybe that property was a method in disguise, and used my favorite decompiler to find out.

This is the scheme/pattern I came across:

```
internal MyClass() : ISomeInterface
{
    Locker = new object();
}

public object Locker { get; private set; }

private SomeObject _myProperty;
public SomeObject MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            if (_myProperty== null)
                MyProperty = SomeCondition ? SomeMethod() : Something.Else;
            return _myProperty;
        }
    }

    private set
    {
        _myProperty = value;
    }
}
```

Am I correct to believe that whenever `_myProperty` is `null`, the getter calls the setter and there's a *race condition* bug here that may be causing the random/occasional freezing I'm experiencing? How can I confirm/infirm that this freezing is effectively a *deadlock*?

What would be a correct implementation? I'm led to believe that if the setter also had a `lock (Locker)` (I don't like the `Locker` being publicly accessible either, sounds like asking for trouble), and the getter would assign `_myProperty` instead of calling the setter, it'd be thread-safe.

Lastly, is there a way I can call this getter without requiring the 3rd party to ship a "fixed" version, and without freezing?

I have tried calling it from the main UI thread, I have tried calling it from a `Task` / background thread, I have tried a `Sleep(200)` before the call, I have tried setting a timeout on the `Task`... no matter what I do, I don't seem to be able to consistently call that getter and reliably get the expected result (it *does* work... sometimes).

The `Locker` object is public, but it's defined in an `internal class` that I only access via its interface, which of course doesn't expose it. Is there a way I can use reflection to *acquire the lock from the outside* (`Monitor.TryEnter(magicallyObtainedLocker)`) and actually get it to work? Or is that getter completely [*borked*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=borked)?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I just wanted to say "YUCK!" to that getter/setter combination. That's just...awful!

Comment: There's a reason @retailcoder is a beloved user on [codereview.se] - He wants to avoid having to deal with code like this!

Comment: Unfortunately, I think your best bet is going to be getting the third party to fix their library :(

Comment: Use your favorite decompiler to figure out who else is using that locker!

Answer (score 5):

> Am I correct to believe that whenever _myProperty is null, the getter calls the setter and there's a race condition bug here that may be causing the random/occasional freezing I'm experiencing? How can I confirm/infirm that this freezing is effectively a deadlock?

No.  In C#, `lock` is reentrant for the same thread.  You can see this in the documentation for [Monitor.Enter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx):

> It is legal for the same thread to invoke Enter more than once without it blocking; however, an equal number of Exit calls must be invoked before other threads waiting on the object will unblock.

---

> don't like the Locker being publicly accessible either, sounds like asking for trouble

I agree with you here.  This is more likely the culprit.  The fact that `Locker` is public most likely means that something else in the library is locking on this object, which *could* be the cause of the deadlock.

If you can run this through the Visual Studio Concurrency Profiler, you should be able to pause at the deadlock, and see the objects blocking at that point in time.

Comment: *Find Usages* on the `Locker` yields few results, all in getters set up like this, all in the same class; this getter is the only one that's calling the setter though. Seems to be public with a YAGNI stamp...

Comment: @retailcoder The fact that you're getting an appcrash suggests that it's probably a problem in `SomeMethod` or one of the properties that's accessed in the getter, actually...

Comment: So it can't have anything to do with the property *playing with itself*, nor with multithreading?

Comment: @retailcoder The property "playing with itself" is fine.  A deadlock would likely give different behavior, since it'll just cause an infinite hang...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can use reflection to acquire the lock from the outside (Monitor.TryEnter(magicallyObtainedLocker)) and actually get it to work?

Yes, given that you could decompile it, I would guess so<sup>1</sup>; the following '[works on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)':

- "ThirdParty" is built in its own, separate project as a DLL
- "InternalLocker" is a console program in a different project, which references the ThirdParty DLL

<sup>1</sup> I'm guessing you **can** acquire the lock from the outside; and hoping but not predicting whether that will suffice to avoid the deadlock.

---

```
using System;

namespace ThirdParty
{
    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        string MyProperty { get; }
    }

    public static class Factory
    {
        public static ISomeInterface create() { return new MyClass(); }
    }

    internal class MyClass : ISomeInterface
    {
        internal MyClass()
        {
            Locker = new object();
        }

        public object Locker { get; private set; }

        private string _myProperty;
        public string MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                lock (Locker)
                {
                    if (_myProperty == null)
                        MyProperty = "foo";
                    return _myProperty;
                }
            }

            private set
            {
                _myProperty = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using ThirdParty;

namespace InternalLocker
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            test1();
            test2();
        }

        static void test1()
        {
            ISomeInterface thing = Factory.create();
            string foo = thing.MyProperty;
            assert(foo == "foo");
        }

        static void test2()
        {
            ISomeInterface thing = Factory.create();
            // use reflection to find the public property
            Type type = thing.GetType();
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Locker");
            // get the property value
            object locker = propertyInfo.GetValue(thing, null);
            // use the property value
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(locker))
            {
                string foo = thing.MyProperty;
                Monitor.Exit(locker);
                assert(foo == "foo");
            }
            else
                assert(false);
        }

        static void assert(bool b)
        {
            if (!b)
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```